Nginx: redirect and php-fpm
I want to rewrite requests for the url http(s)://mydomain.com/_matrix/push/v1/notify to http(s)://mydomain.com/nextcloud/index.php/apps/uppush/gateway/matrix. I use nginx with php-fpm. I have set-up the following location block:
location =/_matrix/push/v1/notify {
    set $custom_request_uri /nextcloud/index.php/apps/uppush/gateway/matrix;
    rewrite ^.*$ /nextcloud/index.php/apps/uppush/gateway/matrix last;
}

Unfortunately this works only partially: It seems like nginx is picking up the first part and rewriting to /nextcloud/index.php but then the php-application (nextcloud) gives the error message The requested uri(/_matrix/push/v1/notify) cannot be processed by the script. It seems that nginx is still passing the original URI to the PHP script.
I cannot use return instead of rewrite because the user application does not work with return. How can I rewrite this correctly for PHP?

I just want to make sure we're clear. You want to rewrite, not redirect, right? If so it might help to update the question to remove things like "I want to redirect requests".

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

Most likely the nextcloud app relies on the value of REQUEST_URI FastCGI parameter, which is assigned to the $request_uri variable value at the fastcgi_params file. This internal nginx variable is read-only and does not get changed with the internal URI rewrites. You can try to overwrite REQUEST_URI parameter value using the following directive: fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $custom_request_uri if_not_empty; under your PHP handler location. Make sure to include this directive after the include fastcgi_params; (or similar one) directive.

@IvanShatsky, thank you very much. This works!

Glad to hear this works! May I write this as an answer so you can accept it?

@IvanShatsky: Please do so that I can accept.

Hi Ivan, how can I accept your solution as the answer?

I need to write an answer first :) I want to include some additional explanations to it, and since I'm not a native English speaker, it can take some time for me to do it. Actually, I was just about to do this today, so please check this thread a few hours later.

Solution 1:
location / {
        rewrite ^/_matrix/push/v1/notify(.*)$ $scheme://$host/nextcloud/index.php/apps/uppush/gateway/matrix redirect;
}

Solution 2:
location /_matrix/push/v1/notify {
        return 302 $scheme://$host/nextcloud/index.php/apps/uppush/gateway/matrix;
}

Solution 3:
location /_matrix/push/v1/notify {
        rewrite ^/.*$ /nextcloud/index.php/apps/uppush/gateway/matrix redirect;
    }

Solution 4:
location /_matrix/push/v1/notify {
        proxy_pass $scheme://$host/nextcloud/index.php/apps/uppush/gateway/matrix;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

PHP solution 1:
$ch = curl_init();
// Enable following redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

PHP solution 2:
// Create a stream context with HTTP options
$options = [
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'follow_location' => 1, // Enable following redirects
        'header' => "User-Agent: PHP\r\n", // Custom headers (optional)
        'timeout' => 30, // Timeout in seconds (optional)
    ],
];

$context = stream_context_create($options);

// Fetch the content
$response = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


Hi Meruarez, thank you very much for this! Unfortunately Solution 1 and 3 do not work. They lead exactly to the problem that I described above because PHP does not use the rewritten path but the original one. Solution 2 does not work because the client does not follow the return. Solution 4 works (i used something similar initially) but has other issues because it basically introduces an additional reverse proxy.

@Alexander and why client dont want to follow redirect? You cant enable that?

Hi Mertuarez, the client is a Android Push application that I did not write. I cannot enable that.
